# Is the verb "sleep" transitive or intransitive?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? Is the verb "sleep" transitive or intransitive? Thanks.
"Babies sleep eighteen hours."

Comment: It's intransitive. _Eighteen hours_ is a measure phrase and not a direct object. Direct objects can be passivized:+ Bill kicked the ball ==> The ball was kicked by Bill_. Try that on your sentence: **Eighteen hours are slept by babies*. Yuk.

Comment: OED lists some senses/usages as transitive, including *to sleep the sleep of the just* and *to sleep off a bender.* I am not sure the passive test works supremely well and intuitively in the case of those idioms.

Comment: Idioms are sui generis to a fault. They're exceptions, by definition. Interesting, but not productive.

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence you posted, it is an intransitive verb as *eighteen hours* is not an object. A preposition, *for*, is omitted because it is not absolutely required.

*18 hours* is functioning as an "adverb" as in "I have been waiting my whole life for this moment". *My whole life* is not an object of *waiting*. *For* is also omitted before *my*.

*Sleep* can be both intransitive and transitive, as defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep).

We need to be very flexible in determining whether one verb is transitive or intransitive as *sleep* has a transitive verb usage, but it cannot be passivized.

**"to provide sleeping accommodations for: the boat sleeps six"**

It cannot be passivised, but still is a transitive verb.

Answer (score 1):

"Eighteen hours" is a how-long indication, ie an adverbial indication. When you ask after direct objects you ask "whom/what", but not "how long".
So "to sleep" in your example is no transitive verb, because there is no direct object.